# VPN on Windows Server 2012 - Requires Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I am setting up a Windows Server 2012 box.

I want to give users VPN access - I'm happy to use 'local users and groups' - I only need access for 2 users.

Do I need to setup Active Directory to restrict my VPN users to only VPN tasks (eg not be able to login to RDP) - or to even get VPN working?

All the tutorials I have seen talk about Active Directory.

I would like to keep my server as minimal as possible so only want to install AD if absolutely necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Per Documentation as well as per experience - no, you can set that up without AD.